# Android Studio: Sharing a file thru FileProvider error E/FilePathConverter resolveFilePath Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-sharing

I want to share /Internal Storage/aaa/bbb.dat file to another app via FileProvider. But it errors out.

i've put the paths into provider_path.xml and put the provider into manifest file.

```
   // share intent
    private void initShareIntent(String type) {
        boolean found = false;
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("*/*");

        // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) ||
                        info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type) ) {

                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/aaa/bbb.dat");

    // wrap File object into a content provider. NOTE: authority here should match authority in manifest declaration

                    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "org.bramantya.news.copygame.cod.FileProvider", file);

                    share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); // Optional, just if you wanna share an image.


                    share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                return;

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
        }
    }
```

---

```
       final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button


//initShareIntent("midrop");                                                                            
initShareIntent("mail");

                                          if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                                              mInterstitialAd.show();
                                          } else {
                                              Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                                          }
                                      }
        });
```

I expect gmail or midrop/shareme to opens and bbb.dat file attached. But it errors out

```
2019-10-26 10:47:27.582 25559-25584/? E/FilePathConverter: resolveFilePath uri = content://org.bramantya.news.copygame.cod.FileProvider/oblehbleh/aaa/bbb.daterror!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:465)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
        at com.xiaomi.midrop.sender.c.e.a(Unknown Source:31)
        at com.xiaomi.midrop.sender.c.e.c(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.xiaomi.midrop.sender.c.e.a(Unknown Source:44)
        at com.xiaomi.midrop.sender.ui.TransmissionActivity.a(Unknown Source:61)
        at com.xiaomi.midrop.sender.ui.TransmissionActivity$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:362)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.example.app"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/copygame"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="org.bramantya.news.copygame.cod.FileProvider">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>

        </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="oblehbleh" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

I made the code by following these posts

[Android : FileProvider on custom external storage folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074872/android-fileprovider-on-custom-external-storage-folder)
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

and many nmore i cant remember (i'm a total amateur at programming)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

finally it works by changing the provider xml into this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <paths>
        <external-path name="provider" path="/" />
    </paths>
</paths>
```

Comment: A strange story it is.

Comment: @blackapps today i got hit by a strange issue again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576259/android-studio-file-project-structure-missing-options-to-change-application