# Android Studio: file-> "Project Structure" missing options to change application id, version, version name, etc

Tags: android-studio, project-structure

So every time i updated my app, i use `file -> project structure` to increase the version and put version name. I also use it to name application id when i want to fork my codes into different app.

but today I can't find application id, version, version name, etc on file-> "Project Structure".

a few months ago i also got this problem and the options suddenly come back by itself.
so I don't know how to fix it. I need those options...

---

What I've tried

1. loading old projects
2. refreshing Gradle files and sync
3. rebuilding the    project

Answer (score 2):

If the "Sync Project with Gradle" does not appear, open the Android folder separately.i.e like an independent project. File->Open. In my case, I was working on a Flutter/Kotlin project. When I opened the Android folder it automatically started syncing and downloading the required gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

oh my God, fixed it by

1. File > Sync Project with Gradle
2. File > project structure > modules (will still be blank)
3. File > project structure > suggestion -> click APP (bottom right will say "loading" with tiny fonts)
4. File > project structure > modules (now the options will appear)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see "Sync Project with Gradle", but I saw "sync with file system". This worked once, but now Project structure is gone again. Clicking "sync with file system" doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Your project structure may have an issue try opening the Android folder independently i.e like its own project File->Open

Comment: This is what worked for me. I had a Flutter project that had an Android project within it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the keyboard shortcut, for example on Windows is "ctrl+alt+shift+S"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by Open module settings (Right-click the project -> Open module settings) change some value and apply it

then the project structure is showing up